# How to 'track' a turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to track a turtle created as follows:

- time 0: turtle 1 creates a new turtle - object - using hatch-
- time > 0: the object created is added to the list of a new turtle, turtle 2;
- time > 0: turtle 2 wants to share this object with a new turtle, turtle 3. The object is then added to turtle 3's list ...

The turtle to track is the object. I thought about visit a path/link or changing color to the turtle created (for example, ask this-object [ set color red ]), but I am hiding the turtle, so it does not make sense. 
Do you have any idea on how I can track the path of this turtle within the network? (you can think of a car that has an accident, but the driver does not stop, continuing driving and it has a new accident ...
What I would like to track are not only the accidents, but also the cars that have caused them, if it  possible.

I hope you can help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have now asked essentially the same question at least 10 times in slightly different ways. It's clear that none of the answers have answered your question, but it's also clear that you aren't understanding any of the answers. While I would normally ask you to post what you have tried so far, it's probably best to start from the beginning.

Here is a complete model that does what you want. I have put `print` statements at key points so that you can see that it does what you want.

```
breed [people person]
people-own
[ my-objects
]

breed [objects object]
objects-own
[ my-people
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-people 5
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color red
    set my-objects []
  ]
  ask one-of people
  [ hatch-objects 1
    [ set color blue
      set my-people (list myself)
      let child self
      ask myself [ set my-objects (list child) ]
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask one-of objects [move-object]
  tick
end

to move-object
  let target one-of people
  while [target = first my-people] [set target one-of people]
  let this-object self
  ask target
  [ type self type " Objects old: " print my-objects
    set my-objects fput this-object my-objects
    type self type " Objects new: " print my-objects
  ]
  type self type " Owners old: " print my-people
  set my-people fput target my-people
  move-to target
  type self type " Owners new: " print my-people
end
```

If you want to make any progress on your code, you need to completely understand this model first. Don't just copy the relevant bits into your code and try to amend. Instead, make a new NetLogo model for this code and understand every line - what it does, how it works. Once you understand it, you can then use the concepts and approach in your own model.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have asked similar question to do something approximately the same. However I met difficulties not in using them and not in understanding. Manuals and other material on the web is not completely satisfying and I am still learning this programming code. I cannot write the whole code but only relevant parts for the problem, and this explains why it has been difficult to include all your suggestion in the code. It is not something easy, not for me at least. And I have really appreciated your help

Comment: Another question that I have asked and it is not clear to me is how to plot this information (object) through time (ticks) and see its behaviour, i.e. something that can tell me when the object was created and how it was spread within the network. I could ask for another question but it would be the 11th on the same problem.

Comment: And I have said repeatedly that you are trying to build too much of your model at once. You need to get a simple version of your model completely working the way you expect before adding more stuff that doesn't work.

Comment: But the doubts regarding the issue, on how to do something that I do not know how to do, will be staying there, unfortunately even with a simple version of the model.